# Windows 10: How to prevent HDMI audio cut off on display blanking

Tags: windows-10, audio, hdmi, standby

- Having laptop with AMD graphics, using it to output image also as the sound to Dell display where external speakers are connected.
- Windows 10 display settings say *"10 minutes of idle to switch off the display"*.
- When the display is switched to standby (image data stream stopped?), also the audio data stream is stopped - which is undesirable.

**Is there any way, how to instruct OS not to stop the audio?**

It's perfectly fine to have display power saving (the image), but the audio is still needed. No luck searching the OS settings nor the Display's OSD setup menu.

Comment: Just ran into this with Windows 11 as well. MSI laptop, RTX mobile. I thought it was my USB-c "Dock" with the headphone jack as it would occasionally go to that audio, but it just happened without any dock at all. I just had it happen and it persists through a 'hibernate' as well.

Answer (score 0):

**TLDR**: Find your Nvidia or AMD audio driver and disable it in Device Manager.

[Disable Nvidia HD Audio Driver](https://i.stack.imgur.com/da2RL.png)

When you connect your computer to an external monitor with a built-in speaker through a Display Port cable, the computer will add a new sound device to its sound device list.

When the screen goes into saving mode (turn blank), the audio of the computer will be interrupted for a second, and one of my game's sound is turned off completely even when the screen is out of saving mode.

At first, I tried to disable the monitor speaker in the sound device list of Windows, but it doesn't solve the issue.

Turned out, when you connect an external monitor with HDMI or Display Port cable, it doesn't just transfer image data through the cable but also audio data. When the screen turns off (saving mode), the computer cut off the cable connection, which cut off the image transfer, and also interrupts the audio of the whole system, which is weird because I never use the audio of the display in the first place (I have disabled monitor sound device).

Finally, I found out that to process the audio transfer from your monitor to your computer through HDMI or Display Cable, your GPU (Nvidia or AMD) needs a driver. In my case with Nvidia card, Nvidia HD Audio driver is the driver that processes this. So I turned off it in the Device Manager and it works, no more sound interruption.

Comment: `...AMD graphics, using it to output image also as the sound to Dell display...`, so when I disable it, I lose the audio under all circumstances, which is not what is requested. I want to use it, even in the display standby mode.

Comment: But due to the explained reasons there is only one connection that transfers video and audio. When the display goes into StandBy mode it cuts off that connection -> no sound. All you can do is prevent it from turning off and just go "black". Might be something in the display's settings.